# Pass each line of a file as an argument to a command?

Tags: bash, shell

The contents of `file.txt` are like this:

```
arg1 sometext
arg2 othertext
arg3 more and more text
```

etc. I want that *each line* of `file.txt` be passed as an argument to a `command`, that is, like:

```
command "arg1 sometext" "arg2 othertext" "arg3 more and more text" ...
```

Note that each line of `file.txt` can contain white spaces. So what separates different arguments in `file.txt` are newlines. How can I do this?

Comment: `BufferedReader`? Where did that come from?

Comment: `cat file.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 command`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xargs -d '\n' -a file.txt command
```

or

```
(IFS=$'\n'; command $(< file.txt))
```